# Как упростить класс подключения к PDO в PHP

Tags: php, классы, pdo

Есть class DB, к сожалению или к счастью, я перфекционист, уделяю особое внимание дизайну кода. 10 лет юзал апи мускул и мускул импрув, сейчас перехожу на PDO (лучше поздно чем никогда). Нашел на хабре класс DB с функцией для прогона запросов через prepare и execute. Это то что мне нужно, но мне не нравится блок подключения к базе данных, я уверен, что там есть лишние конструкции, помогите упростить этот класс.

```
<?php

 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_NAME', 'DB_NAME');
 define('DB_USER', 'DB_USER');
 define('DB_PASS', 'DB_PASS');
 define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

 class DB {
    protected static $instance = null;

    public function __construct() {}
    public function __clone() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            $opt = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE,
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function run($sql, $args = [])
    {
        $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
 }

?>
```

Comment: По моему все настройки в instance $opt всегда такие, а значит дефолтные. Скорее всего можно просто написать **new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS)**.
Даже можно убрать charset из dsn.

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать пример, относительно моего первого варианта?

Answer (score 0):

По моему ничего не нужно усложнять. Чего-то подобного хватит для стабильной работы. По крайней мере хватает сполна.

```
Сlass DB {
    private static function con() {
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', '');
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
        $stmt = self::con()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data;
    }
}
```